# How to show buttons horizontally in uipopoverviewcontroller

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I want to create a popoverviewcontroller with 3 buttons only(Add, Delete, Edit). It should show horizantally.
I used Action sheet but its showing vertically. How to achieve this?

Thanks

--J

Comment: can you put your code of buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a Viewcontroller with 3 buttons horizontally and there action
- set the contentsizeInPopover in the viewDidLoad method
- Set the Xib to freeform and make the desired size with buttons

show popover

```
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:senderButton.bounds inView:senderButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```